# java -version couldn't execute java file

Tags: java, linux, java-8

java file in the directory; java command not working; .bashrc entry for java variable:

```
root@s1:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin# ls -ltr | grep java

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   2293 Dec 12  2018 javapackager

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   2293 Dec 12  2018 javafxpackager

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143 120604 Dec 16  2018 javaws

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   1809 Dec 16  2018 java-rmi.cgi

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   7412 Dec 16  2018 javap

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   7412 Dec 16  2018 javah

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   7416 Dec 16  2018 javadoc

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   7412 Dec 16  2018 javac

-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   7332 Dec 16  2018 java

root@s1:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin# java -version

bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java: No such file or directory

root@s1:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin# cd

root@s1:~# cat .bashrc 

# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)

# for examples

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Hello, I'm trying to install hadoop in virtualbox. I've extracted java packages in `/usr/lib/jvm`. When running java commands it's couldn't execute the java file in the path `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java`.
You can also see all the users have execute permission.

Please help me identify the issue.

Comment: Run `echo $PATH` to see what `PATH` is actually set to.  Chances are that that `.bashrc` has not been "sourced".

Comment: (The owner and group for the files seems odd, but that shouldn't cause this problem.  The files are executable by anyone.  Unless this is some kind of "mandatory access control" problem; e.g. SELinux or AppArmor related.  Or ... possibly ... Docker containers or the like.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `./java --version`
on Linux bash you need to specify "./" for executables.